# Case Correction when editing questions

Tags: discussion, editing

Really, what's the point? It seems a little heavy-handed and discouraging to new users, and doesn't add / change anything for search engine results of the question. Non-native English speakers, dyslexics etc may be really offended by it. Can it be toned down please.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're complaining about? What do you think may offend non-native English speakers and dyslexics?

Comment: Case correction, and minor typos

Comment: Are you talking about comments regarding people's spelling, or about edits? How could editing a question to correct the spelling be offensive or discouraging?

Comment: I'm talking about others editing questions just to change the case of a word. It's really minor, and well useless/pointless. Hoe could it be offensive or discouraging? It's pointless, the site is about software recommendations not, how to type English goodly.

Comment: I am a non-native English speaker, and I'm a bit offended that you'd want me to suffer from the additional cognitive load of wading through misspelled questions. It's a good thing that the first person to notice corrects what needs correcting.

Comment: From what I can see, you're trying to build your community, being heavy-handed with very minor typos / capitilisations is off-putting and anally retentive.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how this is being "heavy-handed". The action of editing has *no negative effect* on you.

Comment: You keep saying “heavy-handed”, but I don't think you understand what it means. Editing a post does not penalize anyone. And please [be nice](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: I am a native English speaker, and I understand fully what it means. Just because it doesn't penalise in terms of rep, it doesn't mean that it affects anyone. Heavy-handed and over-used editing just signals a site where precise use of the Queen's English is more important than good answers which I don't think is the route any SE site should go down.

Comment: You might not have understood how this site works then. Editing other people's posts is one of the most normal things on SE, all content being understood as placed under CC-BY-SA (see the very end of the page for a link to more details, and Undos answer). As Gilles already pointed out, there are already language barriers for non-native speakers. Being a native, you might not know what that could mean to someone not fluent in English at all. I didn't see anyone offended yet, quite the contrary I was even thanked for this, as it also improves chances of good answers.

Comment: y'all better keep off irc then.

Answer (score 8):

The Stack Exchange system is built around peer editing. Everyone is encouraged to correct mistakes when they see them. If they have the editing privilege, they should use it to correct what's wrong. If not, they're encouraged to suggest an edit.

It's not offensive, and it's not meant to be at all. It's simply the community helping you make your post better. And through doing that, they help make the site as a whole better. This is exactly how it's supposed to work.

If you can bring up a specific case of this being offensive to you, then we can talk more specifically.

Comment: So, are you stating that a word that hasn't got the correct casing is "wrong" and needs to be corrected? e.g. "html" to "HTML"

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be, but if someone donates some time to help make your post better by capitalizing it correctly, that's a *good thing*.

Comment: *needs* to be corrected is a bit strong but I would say if there are other correction than yes fix that as well. I often fix typos and minor grammar and capitalization but usually only fix minor things if I'm doing more - or there is multiple minor things.

Comment: @user3791372 Yes, a word that isn't spelled properly (whether the problem is capitalization or something else) should be corrected. Why would you want to force every reader to make the correction mentally, which (especially with non-native readers) may increase the cognitive difficulty considerably?

Comment: Html vs HTML vs html all use the same letters, so are not spelt incorrectly. ThmH would be a different issue.

Comment: @user3791372 HTML is much easier to read and parse than Html is, and HTML is correct. So Html should be corrected.

Comment: To pick up this very example: with lowercase "html" my mind makes a tiny "loop" to figure the *word* first before recognizing the *term* behind the letters (I often find myself reading it twice). With uppercase "HTML" it directly snaps the term, as I no longer need to "capitalize it mentally" – exactly as Gilles put it in his comment, which I'd upvote twice if I could. We do not really read by putting together letters, our brains are capable of recognizing proper groups of them like pictures.